# How can i fix MongoDB Database-Differ Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

am tryna make an API
and i've created a Totally new Project and cluster and Collection for it
and when i try to use mongoose.save() to populate my database
the err message shows

```
  "message": {
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 13297
  }
```

and all the explainations i've seen is talking about DBs with similar names like Test and test could cause that
but all my DBs/Collections are differently named ...
please help.... am still learning Mongo

Comment: Without any code, we will not be able to help you. Take the time to create the minimal code to reproduce the error and post it here

Comment: 13297 is a DatabaseDifferCaseCode, meaning the database it finds differs in capitalization

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you already have a database(e.g. nodeAPI) in the cluster and trying to create new one with difference case but with same name ( e.g. nodeapi, NodeAPI etc.).

Solution:

Either: Delete the database "nodeAPI" from the cluster, if its empty.

OR: Rename the new database you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

Yea i just created another DB in a previous cluster and it works now.... well i idk what happened but the storm is over xD